# tpc.googlesyndication.com appearing as referral in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, double-click-advertising

As the title says, for the last few days we're seeing an increased proportion of our website traffic marked as a referral for tpc.googlesyndication.com

I found this post, which I don't really understand, but which might help: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1011829?hl=en

A few facts about our website:
-We have no organic traffic, it's all coming from paid sources - native advertising networks.
-We don't use Adsense. We use a Doubleclick partner (we have messaged them about this also).

These referrals have been appearing for the last day or two. Since its occurrence, our average pageviews per user has gone down significantly, and also our revenue per mil has gone down significantly.

We're not sure whether this is just a reporting issue caused by this referral source interfering with our statistics.

So basically, can anyone offer more information or explanation about what's causing this referral, or its implications?

My inclination is to think that some of our paid traffic is "intercepted" by something to do with Doubleclick - and that this traffic is then marked as a referral in Analytics, rather than as from our paid traffic source. I don't understand why this would be happening though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to website management and unlikely to involve code problem in current state.

Comment: Side note: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ may be more appropriate for this question.